# Python using Textfsm it works but not in a function

Tags: python, traceroute, python-textfsm

I'm trying to write a function to parse a traceroute.

It will work if I just have it plain code but not if I put it in a function using a variable.  When I put it in a function I get exit code 0 but the list is empty. Works if I replace the variable with a string.

I'm using windows, win11 laptop and a win2016 server.  I've tried with different python versions: 3.6, 3.8 & 3.11 Also tried in Idle, pycharm and Visual Code but always the same results.

Most grateful for any help with this, thanks

This works - no function:

```
import textfsm

# Load the TextFSM template
with open("templates/traceroute_template.textfsm") as template_file:
    template = textfsm.TextFSM(template_file)

# Read the traceroute output from a file or a variable
trace_output = """
1  1.1.1.1  0.735 ms
2  2.2.2.2  0.589 ms
3  3.3.3.3  1.122 ms
"""

# Parse the traceroute output
parsed_data = template.ParseText(trace_output)
print(parsed_data)

Outputs as expected:
[['1', '1.1.1.1'], ['2', '2.2.2.2'], ['3', '3.3.3.3']]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However when I try and put it in a function the list comes back empty?

```
import textfsm

def get_trace():
    # Load the TextFSM template
    with open("templates/traceroute_template.textfsm") as template_file:
        template = textfsm.TextFSM(template_file)

    # Read the traceroute output from a file or a variable
    trace_output = """
    1  1.1.1.1  0.735 ms
    2  2.2.2.2  0.589 ms
    3  3.3.3.3  1.122 ms
    """

    # Parse the traceroute output
    parsed_data = template.ParseText(trace_output)
    print(parsed_data)

get_trace()
Empty list:
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If within the function I replace the variable with a string including carriage returns it works:

```
 parsed_data = template.ParseText("""1  1.1.1.1  0.735 ms\r2  2.2.2.2  0.589 ms\r3  3.3.3.3  1.122 ms""")

[['1', '1.1.1.1'], ['2', '2.2.2.2'], ['3', '3.3.3.3']]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

The template is:

```
Value Hop (\d+)
Value IP (\S+)

Start
  ^${Hop}\s+${IP} -> Record
```

Comment: The value of `trace_output` differs between the two versions of the code.  Inside a triple-quoted string, indentation becomes an actual part of the string; the three lines after `trace_output = """` need to be flush left.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper that has fixed it for me. 

Not sure if I'm supposed to tick a thank you box here but very much appreciated.